# Phone Number Rotating Script Not Working On Safari iFrames

Tags: javascript, ios, iframe, safari, phone-number

### Scope:

We use a phone tracking company to dynamically rotate phone numbers on our site. The phone tracking script targets specific phone numbers (we list the specific "target numbers" in the backend). The script **only** dynamically rotates numbers if the url parameter `st-t=paid` is in the url. This is working on the phone numbers located at the top right of the website.

### Problem

We `<iframe>` in landing pages. The phone numbers on the landing pages are **not** rotating on Safari. It seems to work on Chrome and Firefox, just not on Safari and IOS. We need the phone numbers on the "iFrame" to rotate when on the "iFrame Host" - see terms below. Any help is welcomed.

### Elements

Here are the components we're working with:

- **iFrame:** http://static.personandpartnersleads.com/grn/dcjr/landers/new/specials/index.html
- **iFrame Host**: http://greenwaychryslerjeepdodge.com/web-new-vehicle-specials-ddc.htm?st-t=paid
- **Dynamic Rotating Script**:

```js
    var _stk = "862006920f1abc1afd13b8c08d2c7878c364ff54";
    (function(){
        var a=document, b=a.createElement("script"); b.type="text/javascript";
        b.async=!0; b.src=('https:'==document.location.protocol ? 'https://' :
        'http://') + 'd31y97ze264gaa.cloudfront.net/assets/st/js/st.js';
        a=a.getElementsByTagName("script")[0]; a.parentNode.insertBefore(b,a);
    })();
```

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console? (Hit F12 to open your developer tools)

Comment: No, none related to this. @MikeC

Comment: It could be related. Not all browsers are created equally. Really the point is what have you done to determine what the bug is? You need to do a little bit of ground work yourself before you'll get much/any help on Stack Overflow.

Comment: New to Stack Overflow. Just trying to solve the problem. It's a 3rd party code/tool. I've been down many roads with this problem lately. I'm a marginal novice.